# Problems with setting screensaver timeout on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, screensaver

So I have set the windows screensaver timeout to a high amount of time(10h). The problem is, that I would like to lower the screensaver timeout. I cannot do that using the control panel, because while trying to set it to 10h contorl panel refused to work, so I changed the **registry**<sup>dramatic music intensifies</sup> using regedit. But now I can no longer find the registry key I modified. *Facepalm*

Any idea where the changed key is located?

Comment: I typically would just use the Settings application to define the screensaver.  So I could not confirm this location on a system with a screensaver, but it should be defined at `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\ControlPanel\Desktop`

Comment: Sadly, I didn't find any keys at that location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for help!

> I typically would just use the Settings application to define the screensaver. So I could not confirm this location on a system with a screensaver, but it should be defined at Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\ControlPanel\Desktop – Ramhound

The key was at

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Control Panel\Desktop
```

So HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE instaed of HKEY_CURRENT_USER.